# Unexpected 2D Gaussian fit parameters in python

Tags: python, least-squares, curve-fitting

I am doing some work which requires fitting a Gaussian to a cluster of points which is expected to be distributed normally.

I have data which looks like this, you can see the small tightly grouped cluster of points on the left:

[image]

I zoom in around the cluster, and use scikit-learn KDE to get a density distribution (with Gaussian kernel), which looks like this:

[image]

Then I fit the Gaussian and it turns out to have far too small sigma:

```
centroid_x: -36.3204357 
centroid_y: -12.8734763
sigma_x:     0.17916588
sigma_y:     0.07428976
```

[image]

From inspection of the density distribution, the x and y sigma should be more on the order of ~1, rather than ~0.1. Does anyone know why this behaviour might be occurring? I don't believe there are significant errors in my code or method, this technique has worked well on other data sets, for example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you isolating the points (i.e., does the data set you're fitting to consist of **only** the points visible in the second plot)? Do you set initial values?

Comment: Hi! the fitting is only done with the points shown in the second plot. For initial values I use the mean and standard deviations of the x and y arrays

Comment: I am unconvinced there is anything the matter, because you haven't shown the points in sufficient detail.  Your graphics and results are perfectly consistent, assuming there is a pile of very closely clustered points near $(-36.5, -13).$ What have you done to investigate this possibility?

Comment: Can you post the points you're fitting to, so that we could experiment?